# Why Gcc compiles code in a wrong way?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, avr

I'm trying to find our why my program for AVR ATtiny861A (8 bit) not working. Now I'm just start to use Atmel Studio (previously I used CodeVision AVR).

The assembler code with initial C code in comments is the following:

```
        if(data & 0x8000)
  84:   33 23           and r19, r19
  86:   14 f4           brge    .+4         ; 0x8c <WriteDAC+0x2e>
```

I can not understand how this code can work correctly.

Codevision compiles correctly:

```
; 0000 00EE     (data&0x8000) ? (DAC_DIN=1) : (DAC_DIN=0);
    SBRS R17,7
    RJMP _0x10
```

I'm posting only the part of code I can not understand.

Answer (score 4):

The `AND` instruction sets the condition codes according to the result, which is the same value as the input. Since you are testing the topmost bit, the result is negative, so a conditional branch can simply test this flag with the "greater or equal" condition and use it for a conditional branch, which corresponds to the `if` statement.

The codevision compiler is asked to generate a variable that is 0 or 1, depending on the topmost bit (so you have different source code: one is an `if` statement, the other a ternary expression), <strike>which is done by shifting the bit down and filling the register with zeros</strike>, which it does by using a different kind of conditional jump.

Both are fully correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `BRGE` instruction performs a `Branch if Greater or Equal Signed`

Since performing an `and` operation with `0x8000` is equal to test for a sign bit in a 16-bit operand, it will set the sign bit and the branch will execute.

---

The `SBRS` performs a `Skip if Bit in Register is Set`

Performing an `and` operation with `0x8000` is equal to test the seventh bit in the upper byte of a 16-bit operand.

---

These instructions can be managed to perform the same result, so I assume each compiler did it it's own way, by the bit of code you posted.

If they behave differently, please post more of it and let's deliberate.

References:

http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_BRGE.html

http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_SBRS.html